# Wrapfig pushes section text out of the page

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment, wrapfigure

`wrapfig` works perfectly with all text except the sections. It seems to push the section text out of the page to the left. The only section text that is still showing is the one the `wrapfig` command is inside of.

```
\documentclass[margin,line]{res}


\oddsidemargin -.5in
\evensidemargin -.5in
\textwidth=6.0in
\itemsep=0in
\parsep=0in
% if using pdflatex:
%\setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{\paperwidth}
%\setlength{\pdfpageheight}{\paperheight} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{floatflt}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color,hyperref}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[icelandic]{babel}
\newenvironment{list1}{
  \begin{list}{\ding{113}}{%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{0in}
      \setlength{\parsep}{0in} \setlength{\parskip}{0in}
      \setlength{\topsep}{0in} \setlength{\partopsep}{0in} 
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{0.17in}}}{\end{list}}
\newenvironment{list2}{
  \begin{list}{$\bullet$}{%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{0in}
      \setlength{\parsep}{0in} \setlength{\parskip}{0in}
      \setlength{\topsep}{0in} \setlength{\partopsep}{0in} 
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{0.2in}}}{\end{list}}

\newenvironment{innerlist}[1][\enskip\textbullet]%
        {\begin{itemize}[#1,leftmargin=*,parsep=0pt,itemsep=0pt,topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt]}
        {\end{itemize}}
\begin{document}

\name{Eiríkur Rafn Björnsson \vspace*{.1in}}

\begin{resume}


\section{\sc Persónu upplýsingar}
  \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.2\textwidth}
         \vspace{-1cm}
        \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{eg.jpg}
        \end{center}
         \vspace{-1cm}
    \end{wrapfigure}
\vspace{.05in}
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{2in}p{4in}}
{\it Heimilisfang:}   Álfheimar 72            & {\it Sími:}   5685024 / 6902898  \\            
{\it Póstnúmer:}  104 Reykjavík   & {\it Fax:}    (412) 268-7828 \\         
{\it Kennitala:} 3107902659 & {\it E-mail:}  eirikurrb10@ru.is\\  \\     

\end{tabular}
```

Comment: surely you're not allowed a paragraph inside a wrapfigure (\begin/\end{center} will create a para break).  actually, i don't see why you need to centre at all, given that you're putting an object inside a box that has the same width.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you want to achieve. You have a 6in text width and a tabular more than 6in wide: the graphic object has not enough space.

Comment: With LaTeX, you'd want to use `\emph{stuff}` instead of `{\it stuff\/}`. The argument is: more semantic and it will "scope" bättre.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of issues with the code. Firstly you do not need the `wrapfig` environment. You can remove it and place the picture within the tabular, here is the code fragment:

```
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{2in}p{2in}p{1in}}
{\it Heimilisfang:}   Álfheimar 72 & {\it Sími:} 5685024 / 6902898 
 &\vskip-10pt\vbox to 0pt{\includegraphics[width=1in]{./graphics/amato}} \\            
\end{tabular}
```

By placing the photo in a `\vbox` of zero height, the photo will overflow in the cells below. The spacing and sizing you can adjust to suit.

[image]

I have used inches for sizing of the cells as you did (I never thought Iceland is using Imperial units).